# Method of coefficients division with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Divide $14x^4+45x^3y+78x^2y^2+45xy^3+14y^4$ by $2x^2+5xy+7y^2$

Since every term in the dividend has dimension $4$, and every term in the divisor has dimension $2$, I can use the method of coefficients:

$2, 5, 7$ $\begin{vmatrix}
14 & 45 & 78 & 45 & 14 \\
14 & 35 & 49 &  \\
 & 10 & 29 & 45 \\
 & 10 & 25 & 35 \\
 &  & 4 & 10 &14 \\
 &  & 4 & 10 &14 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$ $7, 5,2$

Therefore the quotient has the coefficients $7,5,2$. Now I don't know  how to proceed. Which variables and which powers are with which coefficients? I've solved this problem the straight-up way and the quotient is $7x^2+5xy+2y^2$. But there must be a way to instantly write it down in the method of coefficients without resorting to inspection, but I just don't know how in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Since you wrote $14$ first, you've assumed that $x$ is the "main" variable.  This calculation is exactly the same as if you substituted $y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You are already finished. Here is an easier way.  Writing
$$
14x^4+45x^3y+78x^2y^2+45xy^3+14y^4=(ax^2+bxy+cy^2)(2x^2+5xy+7y^2)
$$
immediately gives $(a,b,c)=(7,5,2)$, so the factor is $7x^2 + 5xy + 2y^2$.